# MySQL View Created - Running queries against it takes minutes

Tags: mysql, view

I've turned the following query into a view table names salesboard:

```
select 
distinct(p.paymentID) AS paymentID,
j.jobID AS jobID,j.jobNumber AS jobNumber,j.jobType AS jobType, j.countType AS countType, j.countID AS countID,
ui.userID AS salesRep,
(
    case 
        when (j.idType = 'dealership') then d.dealershipName 
        when (j.idType = 'Group') then g.groupName 
        when (j.idType = 'Agency') then a.agencyName 
    end
) AS dealershipName,
(
    case 
        when (p.manualTimestamp <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00') then p.manualTimestamp 
        when (p.manualTimestamp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') then from_unixtime(p.timestamp) 
    end
) AS checkTS,
p.paymentAmount AS paymentAmount,
po.estimatedMailArrival AS estimatedMailArrival 
from jobs j 
left join smdealershipjoins smdj on j.dealershipID = smdj.dealership 
left join smgroupjoins smgj on j.dealershipID = smgj.groupID 
left join smagencyjoins smaj on j.dealershipID = smaj.agencyID 
join userinfo ui on 
(
    case 
        when (j.idType = 'dealership') then (smdj.sm = ui.userID) 
        when (j.idType = 'Group') then (smgj.sm = ui.userID) 
        when (j.idType = 'Agency') then (smaj.sm = ui.userID) 
    end
) 
left join dealerships d on smdj.dealership = d.dealershipID 
left join dealershipgroups g on smgj.groupID = g.groupID 
left join agencies a on smaj.agencyID = a.agencyID 
join payments p on j.jobID = p.jobID 
left join purchaseorders po on j.jobID = po.jobID 
order by 
(
    case 
        when (p.manualTimestamp <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00') then p.manualTimestamp 
        when (p.manualTimestamp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') then from_unixtime(p.timestamp) 
    end
) desc
```

The view saved and returns the expected results.  However, whenever I run even the simplest of queries on the new view table, the query takes minutes to run.  I've searched around to see if there's anything I could do to fix it - but i've come up empty handed :(

Is there anything that can be done?  I've racked my brain and figured I'd ask for some help.

Comment: Whenever I see a query with heaps of `JOIN` statements and several `CASE` statements, I see a query that's going to take an eternity to run. Are you sure you can't simplify this? Have you checked that things are indexed correctly? What does `EXPLAIN` have to say?

Comment: What really complicates this query is checkTS and idType.  The project has just evolved so much from where it started.  I'm basically just putting bandaids on everything until I get a chance to roll out v2.0.  Basically, i have to check to see if Accounting put a manual timestamp on checks.  If they did, i use it.  If they didn't, i use the timestamp from the form submit.  Also, i have to check to see if a job is for a dealership, group, or agency - and depending on that, i have to pull the client name from the appropriate table.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of any result-set exceeds the size of your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` you query will take an extraordinary amount of time due to I/O paging. In your case, every table included in your from statement must be loaded in to memory because of the `ORDER BY` clause.

Reduce the amount of data being pulled by using partitioning or increase the size of your buffer pool.

Comment: My innodb_buffer_pool_size was set to 16 MB... i changed it to 128.  I'll play around with it and see if everything runs smoother.  Also, if i were to remove the "ORDER BY" - and just do it in my queries - how drastically would that help things?

Comment: The sort runs in `O( n log(n) )` where `n` is the number of elements you're sorting. If `n = a + b + c + d + e` I suppose `a log(a) < n log(n)`

Comment: 16MB is nothing. Crank that to several *gigabytes* or you're going to be in hot water. On a dedicated database server, you should be committing about 50% of your total RAM to that pool. Throwing more might degrade performance only because it eats into OS disk buffer memory. As far as I know, this general buffer pool is used for a lot of things, including caching indexes, which can massively improve performance.